# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RestController

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm working in a new Nest.js project and whenever I try to start the server:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RestController (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the RestModule context.
```

I've checked the documentation and looked everywhere and i cannot spot the problem. The `RestController` class injects `UsersService`, which is exported by `UsersModule` and imported in `RestModule`. Everything looks fine but didn't work.

This is my code:

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RestModule } from './rest/rest.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    RestModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`rest.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RestController } from './rest.controller'
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    RestController
  ]
})
export class RestModule { }
```

`rest.controller.ts`:

```
import { Controller, Inject, Get } from '@nestjs/common'
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service'
import { User } from '../users/user.interface'

@Controller()
export class RestController {

  constructor (
    @Inject()
    private readonly usersService: UsersService
  ) { }

  @Get()
  async getAll (): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersService.findAll()
  }

}
```

`users.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { UsersService } from './users.service'

@Module({
  providers: [
    UsersService
  ],
  exports: [
    UsersService
  ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

`users.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { User } from './user.interface'

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  async findAll (): Promise<User[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve([]))
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RestController` class you have to remove the `@Inject()` from your constructor:

```
constructor (
  private readonly usersService: UsersService
) { }
```

`@Inject()` can be used for [non-class-based provider tokens](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens).